# why request header is not passed in get request in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios

I am using `axios`.could you please tell me why my `request header` parameter is not passed in the request .here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-hertz-j7mmd

```
 const abc = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://125.16.74.160:30208/?cicleCode=undefined&pageNumber=0&pageSize=20&role=ZBM",
        { Authorization: "Bearer zad" }
      )
      .then(() => {
        console.log("---");
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };
```

why `Authorization` parameter is not passed in the request header.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify the `headers` property:

```
  .get(
    "https://125.16.74.160:30208/?cicleCode=undefined&pageNumber=0&pageSize=20&role=ZBM",
    { headers:{ Authorization: "Bearer zad" } }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.get("https://125.16.74.160:30208/?cicleCode=undefined&pageNumber=0&pageSize=20&role=ZBM", 
{ headers: { Authorization: "Bearer zad" } })
.then(() => {
  console.log("---");
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log(e);
});
```